# SDK error erased the class

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I do not know exactly how to phrase the question, but the Eclipse crashed and when restarted, so one of the classes returned:
[image]

I have no ideia what to do.

Comment: Restore Windows on some backup point in the past, Eclipse probably corrupted the file and it's already damaged.

Comment: Woh ! Bad idea... Windows restoration point does not restore file state...

Answer (score 0):

Try to close all your files from eclipse, check their state with notepad or anything else, and try to properly close and restart eclipse.

If it doesn't work, redownload Eclipse from the website and try with this version.